# Python Cassandra: An authentication challenge was not sent, this is suspicious because the driver expects authentication

Tags: python, cassandra, database-connection, cassandra-python-driver

I'm trying to connect `cassandraDB` using python. I have used authentication as `PlainTextAuthProvider`. This is my code snippet.

```
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username="foo", password="bar")
cluster = Cluster([1.1.1.1], protocol_version=2, auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect()
session.set_keyspace('keyspace')
cluster.connect()
```

It's throwing following error:

> An authentication challenge was not sent, this is suspicious because the driver expects authentication (configured authenticator = PlainTextAuthenticator)

Comment: What Cassandra version are you using? Are you aware of the [protocol versions](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra.html#cassandra.ProtocolVersion)?

Comment: yeah, I'm using 2.x

Comment: Could you give some more information on your setup? At least cassandra version and driver...

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to print some debug info.

Comment: What authenticator is cassandra using? You can check this in cassandra.yaml file - authenticator

Comment: I have only remote access to connect and read the data.

Answer (score 2):

That's [PYTHON-940](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-940), [added](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/commit/4ff50f63c579446a4702db29f0d8deaa41e2834a) in version 3.14.0 of the driver. It should not be throwing the error, but warning if the connection occurs without auth. The intent is to flag when a client configures, and expects to be using auth, but the server is not. Verify auth settings in `cassandra.yaml`, and check that it's mentioned in `system.log` at startup.